# I have cloned my SSD to an HDD because the SSD needs reformatting. Do I just clone it back once the SSD is reformatted?

Tags: hard-drive, mac, ssd, backup, cloning

I was told I needed to reformat my SSD from exFAT to Mac OS Extended (Journaled) to increase its performance speed. I use it to produce music and some of my plugins were running real slow. I have cloned all the content on my SSD over to a hard drive (Mac OS Extended (Journaled)) using Carbon Copy Cloner.

Once I reformat my SSD, do I simply use the same Carbon Copy Cloner software to clone it back? I assume this is the only way, but I just want to make sure I don't screw anything up as all my music production work and a few important plugins are on there!

Comment: Not sure if it is a 1:1 copy. If so, cloning it back will also clone back how the partition scheme was, which undoes your changes. If you only copy files back, then this will work.

Comment: Is this on a boot drive or just a secondary? Recent macOS much prefers SSDs to be APFS. What OS are you running? & what Mac? How is the SSD connected? @LPChip - CCC doesn't clone the partition map really, it will reform to fit, then add a Recovery if one is needed. It will ensure the drive is bootable… but an ExFAT wouldn't be bootable in the first place, so…idk… I'm just wondering why plugins would be on an ExFAT drive...

Comment: @LPChip Carbon Copy Cloner does not work at a partition level but on a file-system level. What you describe would never happen.

Answer (score 0):

### You should be 100% fine.

> “I was told I needed to reformat my SSD from exFAT to Mac OS Extended (Journaled) to increase its performance speed.”

Small comment but I have no idea how an SSD in a Mac was formatted as exFAT; that is really a “not good” thing. But you are on the road to changing that, so all good!

> “Once I reformat my SSD, do I simply use the same Carbon Copy Cloner software to clone it back?”

100% yes! You cloned to a hard drive and now will switch the direction when the SSD is properly reformatted as Mac OS Extended (Journaled)… Into one piece of temporary storage to another. And using Carbon Copy Cloner software is the best choice; you should be 100% fine.

Remember: SSD or hard drive, your data is 100% the same and the main reason you are doing this is to get away from exFAT. When all is said and done you are simply moving data from one place to another; not changing the contents of the data.

#### Bonus advice: Time Machine…

You also say this:

> “I assume this is the only way, but I just want to make sure I don’t screw anything up as all my music production work and a few important plugins are on there!”

In my opinion, you should be 100% fine. Just ensure the backup of the hard drive is the source and the destination is the SSD.

That said, for the future I highly recommend on you getting an external hard drive as a [Time Machine](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201250) backup if you are concerned about your work being lost.

I have no idea what your core system storage is, but get an external hard drive right is at least twice the size of your system disk and hook it up to your system and enable it as a Time Machine backup. Then macOS will prep the drive for Time Machine and that drive will be used for any/all future Time Machine backups.

Fair warning, an initial backup to Time Machine can take hours — and in some rare cases a day or more — but then after that the incremental backups are fairly quick and will allow you to have multiple “snapshots of your machine to refer to if something goes amiss or literally goes missing.

PS: And don’t pinch pennies on buying external Time Machine backup storage. Cheap and large drives exist but what does that $$$ savings mean if your hard work is lost due to the Time Machine backup dying. I would recommend investing in a high quality external hard drive or — if you have the budget — a high quality SSD external hard drive. That simple investment will pay pack instantly if drive or system failure happens.

Comment: +1, but tbh, running pro audio, I'd double up the Time Machine protection with Backblaze &r offsite HD copies. Nothing like being asked to do a remix 10 years later & you can't find your originals (or worse, your project will no longer load in your modern updated DAW… but that's a story for another day :\

Comment: @Tetsujin Don’t disagree. I mean I have external SSDs for Time Machine nowadays after I started “work from home” last year to add an extra layer of stability; I’ve had a few very cheap hard drives die on me from Time Machine activity.

Comment: I've only ever had 1 Mac drive die suddenly & completely (though a fair number of Win drives), but my data-safe paranoia continues nonetheless ;) It's all Mac Pros here, so TMs are internal, audio except for the current running project  is not actually backed on TM because it's too big. I've a couple of 1TB SSDs for 'current stuff', everything else is on HD internal, + Backblaze & offsite too, reams of DVDs & drives on shelves elsewhere.

Comment: @Tetsujin I bought a 4TB WD drive for about $75. Slow, but had a lot of space for the price. Every 3-4 months this would happen: The drive would endlessly work and make noise for hours. Clearly it was shuffling it’s internal files to do what Time Machine does. But after 3-4 months of that whatever blessed set of drive tables would crash. Meaning the drive was inaccessible. So all I could do was format from scratch again. The drive itself showed no errors. That is what always fixed it: Reformatting. Then when “work from home” happened I was sick of it and just got a 2TB SSD.

Comment: Ouch! Can't say that overall I'm a great fan of TM these days - I use it just for 'oops' events - periodically drives need DiskWarrior running over them, but I've never known it to cause one to actually fail.

Comment: I chalk up that failure directly to buying a cheap $75 4TB drive, not Time Machine which really works well and makes the stress of backups so painless it almost seems crazy anyone would *not* use it.

Comment: Wouldn’t _cloning_ also copy the exFAT formatting back??

Comment: No, it will not copy the exFAT stuff. You are mixing up the name of the software — [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com) — with some disk *cloning* software that is mainly PC-based that will clone the underlying partitions. In the case of Carbon Copy Cloner it is basically an application based on Rsync that *only* copies files; not filesystems or partitions.